# SQL Server query that deletes record either by email or phone Number and reports if it was deleted by either email or phone

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to delete a record from a SQL Server table using either email or phone number information and want to do it with a single SQL query. Both email and phone number columns can be `NULL`.

However, I also need to find out if the record was deleted by email or the phone number (or both is possible). Writing two separate queries is easiest way to go, but is also very inefficient.

Comment: Huh? What do you mean if it was deleted by phone number or email? That doesn't make any sense at all. And where are trying to implement this? In a trigger? You could use a case expression to determine this quite easily.

Comment: @SeanLange Table has number of columns, two of them are `email` and `phoneNum`. Either of them can be a `NULL`. I need a query or stored procedure that deletes the record by `phoneNum` or `email`(passed by client) and also tells me if the record was deleted by `phoneNum` or `email`.

Comment: @K_foxer9 not necessarily accurate; you can use the OUTPUT clause on deletes.

Comment: @JiggsJedi good point; thank you.

Comment: If you don't have a `unique` constraint on email and another `unique` constraint on phoneNum, you might be surprised at the results of a `delete` statement.

Comment: Silly question - what if they return 2 different records (e.g., record 1 matches the `email` and record 2 matches the `phoneNum`)?

Comment: And in what world could you reasonably have a value in phone and email that are the same? There should be some validation in the front end and/or the database to prevent such absurd values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give this a whirl:

```
declare @clientval varchar(100)
set @clientval = '8888888888'


declare @test table (id int identity(1,1), name varchar(100), phone varchar(10), email varchar(100))
declare @output table (name varchar(100), phone varchar(10), email varchar(100), deleteReason varchar(25))

if @clientval is null set @clientval=''

insert into @test (name,phone,email)
values ('dave','5555555555','dave@somecomp.com'),
       ('jim','6666666666','jim@somecomp.com'),
       ('suzy','7777777777','suzy@somecomp.com'),
       ('sean','8888888888','8888888888'),
       ('op',null,null)

--select *, case when isnull(phone,'')=@clientval and isnull(email,'')!=@clientval  then 'Phone' when isnull(email,'')=@clientval and isnull(phone,'')!=@clientval then 'Email' when isnull(phone,'')=@clientval and isnull(email,'')=@clientval then 'Both' end
delete t
output deleted.name, deleted.phone, deleted.email, case when isnull(deleted.phone,'')=@clientval and isnull(deleted.email,'')!=@clientval  then 'Phone' when isnull(deleted.email,'')=@clientval and isnull(deleted.phone,'')!=@clientval then 'Email' when isnull(deleted.phone,'')=@clientval and isnull(deleted.email,'')=@clientval then 'Both' end into @output (name,phone,email,deleteReason)
from @test t
where (isnull(phone,'')=@clientval or isnull(email,'')=@clientval)

select * from @output
```

Comment: You could add one more predicate to your case expression to check if they are both valid for the delete and send "both".

Comment: What about if both are NULL ?

Comment: In the table, or if they are passed in NULL?

Comment: If you move "Both" to be the first predicate you can eliminate the != predicates in the first two conditions. :)

Comment: I added null handling to both situations.  @SeanLange yes true, but I don't like to rely on non-explicit case expressions, just in case stupid happens -- which I do sometimes catch before my second coffee each morning.

Comment: Not sure how that would be non-explicit. Also, not sure why you need the ISNULL in there. If they are NULL it already will by definition be false when comparing on equality. A much simpler version of that case expression. "case when deleted.phone = clientval and deleted.email = clientval then 'both'
 when deleted.phone = clientval  then 'Phone' 
 when deleted.email = clientval then 'Email'
end"

Comment: Of course I had to remove the multiple ampersands because of how SO handles comments.

Comment: I think he's wanting NULL variable pass through to delete rows with NULL column values, so ISNULL is required to do that.  @iSR5 he's absolutely right you can shorten the case if you re-order it, I just prefer to spell it all out.